# Indirect Enum or Class, Which One Should I Use for Building Basic Data Structures

Tags: algorithm, swift, data-structures, swift2

When I tried to practice some basic data structure such as Linked /Doubly Linked/ Recycling Linked / Recycling Doubly Linked List, AVL Tree, Red-Black Tree, B-Tree and Treap by implementing them in Swift 2, I decided to do such things by taking advantage of Swift 2's new feature: indirect enum, because enum makes an empty node and a filled node more semantic than class.

But soonish it was found that for non-recycling linked lists, returning the inserted node after inserting an element makes no sense because the returned value is a value type but not a reference type. It is said that you cannot accelerate next insertion by writing information directly to the returned value because it is a copy of the inserted node but not a reference to the inserted node.

And what's worse is that mutating an indirect enum based node means writing the whole bunch of data of the associative value, which definitively introduces unnecessary system resource consumption, because the associative value in each enum case is a tuple in essence, which is a sort of contiguous data in memory in essence, which is the same to struct but doesn't have per property accessor to enable small bunch of data writing.

So which one should I use for building such basic data structures? Indirect enum or class?

Answer (score 0):

Well it doesn't matter if it's swift 1 or swift 2 cause at the moment `Enum` and `Structures` are `value` types while `Classes` are called by reference. Since you want to use data structures in your code and like you called it yourself calling them by value is no good. You will have to use a `Class` in order for your code to do what you want it to do. Here is an example of a linked list using a `Class`:

```
      class LLNode<T> 
    {
    var key: T? var next: LLNode? var previous: LLNode? 
    } 

          //key printing
        func printAllKeys() 
    {
     var current: LLNode! = head; //assign the next instance 
    while(current != nil) 
    {
     println("link item is: \(current.key)") 
     current = current.next 
    } 
    }

public class LinkedList<T: Equatable> 
{ //create a new LLNode instance private 
var head: LLNode<T> = LLNode<T>() //append a new item to a linked list 
func addLink(key: T) 
{ //establish the head node 
if (head.key == nil) 
{ 
head.key = key;
return; 
} //establish the iteration variables 
var current: LLNode? = head 
while (current != nil) 
{ 
if (current?.next == nil) 
{ 
var childToUse: LLNode = LLNode<T>() 
childToUse.key = key; 
childToUse.previous = current 
current!.next = childToUse; 
break; 
}
 current = current?.next 
} //end while 
} ///end function
```

for more examples using swift and data structures please do visit:
[data structures swift](http://waynewbishop.com/swift/)

Conclusion : Use `Class` if you want to call by reference else use `Enum` or `Struct`